# Ajax UpdatePanelAnimationExtender only works on first use

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have an asp.net ajax updatePanelAnimationExtender that is used to fade a save confirmation message, which looks like this:

```
<ajaxToolkit:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ID="UpdatePanelAnimationExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="uppExp">
            <Animations>
                <OnUpdated>
                    <Sequence>
                     <Parallel duration=".5">
                                <HideAction AnimationTarget="pnlSuccess" Visible="True" />
                            </Parallel>
                            <Parallel duration=".25" Fps="30"> 
                                 <FadeOut AnimationTarget="pnlSuccess"  />            
                            </Parallel> 
                    </Sequence>
                </OnUpdated>
            </Animations>
</ajaxToolkit:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender>
```

It works great the first time it runs, but after that, on subsequent saves it does not run. This only happens in Internet Explorer (7 and 8) it works fine in Firefox and Chrome.
Any ideas on how to get this to work properly in IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably haven't included the code (animation extender) in update panel, so it's not working second time...

Comment: You are correct that it is not in the update panel, but if I do add it to the update panel, I get this error "An extender can't be in a different UpdatePanel than the control it extends. " despite it being in the correct update panel.
The control is also in a tabpanel if that makes any difference.

Comment: let's clear the confusions, add full aspx code and I will try to look into it